# Convert jpg image to gif, png & bmp format using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

How can I convert a single jpg image into 3 different image formats, gif, png and bmp, using PHP?

Comment: Surely you don't want to convert anything to BMP on the web. Non-animated GIF is a waste of bandwidth as well.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You first create an image object out of your file with [imagecreatefromjpeg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php). You then dump that object into different formats (using [imagegif()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) for example):

```
$imageObject = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
imagegif($imageObject, $imageFile . '.gif');
imagepng($imageObject, $imageFile . '.png');
imagewbmp($imageObject, $imageFile . '.bmp');
```

Comment: Note that WBMP is not the BMP as you might know it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wbmp

Comment: great answer, exactly what i was lookking for too

Comment: How do I get a `bmp`? Since wbmp is not bmp, so image viewer in ubuntu says bogus data.

Answer (score 5):

Use libGD — http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: But its a huge library file, Could u pls help me for a perticular one?
which code i have to use?

Answer (score 2):

I've set up a new opensource project on Github that allows reading and saving of BMP files (actual BMP files, not wbmp), and other file formats, in PHP. It's nice and easy to use.

The project is called [PHP Image Magician](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com).