# PHP Copy Blinking Animated GIF image on other gif Image

Tags: php, gd, gif, animated-gif

I have one blinking youtube play button gif image and I have one thumbnail animated gif image.I want to put the youtube play button on that thumbnail image.However I tried to use imagecopy() function as below

```
    $gif_image = imagecreatefromgif($dest_image);
    $src_image = imagecreatefromgif($blink_image);
    imagecopy($gif_image, $src_image, 55, 40, 0, 0, 80, 80);
```

The Image is getting copied but there is no blinking effect of play button on resulting image.

How this can be achieved?

Thanks,
Ronak Shah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create animated gif using the GD library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340342/create-animated-gif-using-the-gd-library)

Comment: No I don't want to create animated gif, but instead I want to copy one animated gif image on other animated gif image.

Comment: Then maybe you should have a look on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/718500/1798341).

Comment: Tried using the Imagekick class but I didn't able to find any way of copying one image into another just like imagecopy function do.Image composite function is still there but its quite different and not exactly does the way I want to achieve.I have one animated play button 80x80 and one thumbnail image 200x200 and I want to copy that play button on that thumbnail image with the animation effect.