# PHP imagecreatefromgif animated + color

Tags: php, animation, php-gd

I'm trying to create a Image with PHP.

With PNG it works pretty well (The Font Colors works!).

But if I'm using GIF, the Fonts dont get Colors (Always white).

And the GIF Image I use for the Background is not Animated!

This is how it works in PNG (Font Color):

```
<?php
    $zeile1 = @file_get_contents('zeile1.txt');
    $zeile1_title = @file_get_contents('zeile1_title.txt');

    $image = imagecreatefrompng("bg_text.png");
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    $finalImage = imagecreatetruecolor(391,300);

    $font = '../banner1/arial.ttf';
    $color = imagecolorallocate($finalImage, 0, 0, 0);

    $font_title = '../banner1/arialbd.ttf';
    $color_title = imagecolorallocate($finalImage, 255, 0, 126);

    imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 2, 130, $color, $font, $zeile1);

    imagettftext($image, 25, 0, 2, 130, $color_title, $font_title, $zeile1_title);

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
?>
```

But now I want a animated gif as background:

```
<?php
    $zeile1 = @file_get_contents('zeile1.txt');
    $zeile1_title = @file_get_contents('zeile1_title.txt');

    $image = imagecreatefromgif("bg_text.gif");
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    $finalImage = imagecreatetruecolor(391,300);

    $font = '../banner1/arial.ttf';
    $color = imagecolorallocate($finalImage, 0, 0, 0);

    $font_title = '../banner1/arialbd.ttf';
    $color_title = imagecolorallocate($finalImage, 255, 0, 126);

    imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 2, 130, $color, $font, $zeile1);

    imagettftext($image, 25, 0, 2, 130, $color_title, $font_title, $zeile1_title);

    header('Content-type: image/gif');
    imagegif($image);
?>
```

Now the Text is only white and the Title text, is not Showing + The image is not animated.

I hope you understand what I mean, because my english is bad :/

Comment: as far as i know, the GD library does not support animated gifs. you'll need an external library, or perhaps imagemagick to make that work.

Comment: PHP/GD doesn't support animated gifs. Here is another question that might help find an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340342/create-animated-gif-using-the-gd-library

Comment: And what is with the Color? Why this dont work?