# Nothing happens when trying to animate a picture with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, mouseevent, mouseover

I read this good article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486961/animated-image-with-javascript) about animating images.

Since, I've tried to mod it so the image animates only when the user hovers his mouse over the boundaries of the image but stops when he mouses outside of them. No dice...

Here's the specs:

HTML:

```
     <html>
<head>
<title></title>
<!-- link header php -->
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<!-- link animation javaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/robot_animation.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>

<!-- the result -->
<div id="robot"></div>

</body>
</html>


CSS:
    #robot {
 width: 150px;
 height: 85px;
 background-image:url(../images/al.jpeg);
 background-color: green;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 0 0;
 }


JS:

     div.onmouseover =(function startAnimation() { 
//set some variables
var frameHeight = 85; 
var frames = 12; 
var frame = 0; 

// grab properties from stylesheet
var div = document.getElementById("robot"); 

//
setInterval(function () 
{ 
    var frameOffset = (++frame % frames) * -frameHeight; 
    div.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + frameOffset + "px"; 
 }, 600); 
 });
```

1. it worked perfectly with the original code
2. mouseover, onmouseover, etc. work perfectly for the ENTIRE PAGE but...
3. when i try to limit effects only to the image, nothing happens on mouseovers
4. i've tried moving var div to the beginning
5. i've tried different event handlers
6. different ID names
7. I've checked for spelling
8. i'm pretty sure this is a syntax problem...

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: Do you need a script? Does your project allow you to use CSS3 animations?

Comment: @j08691: I would like to use jsFiddle but i couldn't figure out how to import the picture into it, let me try again

Comment: Yes, a JSFiddle would be nice. But you definitely need to move `var div = document.getElementById("robot");` to before `onmouseover`. You can't expect to declare a variable inside a function that is called on the variable you are declaring. Yes, variables get hoisted, but javascript has function scoping, so the function in `mouseover` creates a new scope.

Comment: Can we see `robot_animation.js`?

Comment: @Man of Snow: yes, i actually already included it. It is the 3rd bunch of code following the "Js:" starting with "div.onmouseover"

Comment: @user3114031 Give us a fiddle please, all you have to do for images is `<img src = 'http://www.linktoimage' />`

Comment: @Phlume I haven't heard of CSS3 yet, im kind of new to coding, but i'll check it out

Comment: @Man of Snow: Okay, i'm making one now. Now how do you link an image if its on your hard drive not the web? I'm using a local WAMP server for troubleshooting so all my resources are on my hard drive.  [update] okay, another stackoverflow post says that you have to upload all images to the web before you can use them in jsFiddle

Comment: @user3114031 Upload the images to http://imgur.com/ and link to them.

Comment: It doesn't need to be the original image. Just use anything you find.

Comment: @Man of Snow, Juhana okay then, one sec

Comment: needs some cleaning but here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZA3b8/

Comment: If you need a placeholder image, you can use a placekitten ;) http://placekitten.com/ or a placedog... http://placedog.com/

Comment: @yochannah Omg, that is the cutest thing I've ever seen. Why are these pictures not standard in every programming library? As soon as you get frustrated with your code not working just invoke the cuteKittyPictures() function

Comment: i think a jQuery library has to be included in the Fiddle, in my code i included jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: Got this far http://jsfiddle.net/ZA3b8/10/, still working on it