# Create an animated .gif from .jpeg/png

Tags: php, gd

Is it possible to use the GD library to create an animated gif? I want the user to upload a png/jpeg and generate a 2 frame animated gif out of the image. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Create simple animated GIF from two JPEG images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191367/php-create-simple-animated-gif-from-two-jpeg-images)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Create simple animated GIF from two JPEG images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191367/php-create-simple-animated-gif-from-two-jpeg-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good post about it on SO : [Create Animated Gif with Jpeg Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191367/php-create-simple-animated-gif-from-two-jpeg-images)

You can't do it with GD Functions, but there is a class on phpclasses.org to do this, check that : [PHP Classes GIF Animation From](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3163-PHP-Generate-GIF-animations-from-a-set-of-GIF-images.html)

You can also find a good tutorial about it here : [Tutorial Generate Animated GIF PHP](http://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/weblog/php/howto-generate-animated-gif-with-php)

Answer (score 6):

The question is old but here a new library to create animated GIF with PHP: https://github.com/Sybio/GifCreator

Comment: Wow, the API example in your README there looks very impressive! That (your API design, and also the examples) alone is worth a couple of upvotes, great job! I'll give it a try. (UPDATE: tried, liked, [forked](https://github.com/lunakid/AnimGif), fixed, thanks!)