# Is it possible to do animated graphics in PHP?

Tags: php, animation, graphics

I was doing some research the other day and discovered that I can make desktop PHP applications using [PHP GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) and then it hit me:

**Is it possible to draw animations using PHP?**

Is even 3D possible? I'm not asking if it is a good idea or anything, there are tons of scripting languages for that and I'm aware of that! I just  want to know if it is possible! Does anyone know?

Comment: Just FYI, that project was last updated 2 years ago (ironically, it stated that development was still going)

Comment: PHP can include or source scripts. Have you tried including any scripts for animations and running them from a PHP page? I believe they should work.

Comment: Yes, but remember that PHP is a *server side* technology, and that animations are best rendered *client side*.  In other words: generate and send animation frames from the server: BAD.  Generate an "animation" and send all at once, or in relatively large chunks (a Flash file, an HTML5 animation - whatever): BETTER.

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm perfectly aware of that :) What I'm curious about is whether I can make a desktop 3D application using php. And yes, I know this comment is an oxymoron :P

Comment: @Loupax: Theoretically? Sure - PHP can work with images, and if you can make one image, you can make multiple, and if you can make an image, you can render a 3D environment - plus, you *can* do non-web-based scripting with PHP. In practice? It is an absolutely terrible and pointless idea. Use a language and toolset that's actually suited for the job, instead of driving a nail through a wall with a saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation ? Not directly possible with GD, need additional libraries from what I know. 3D drawing ? Yes, it's possible.

Check out these resources:

[Draw a cube with php](http://codentronix.com/2011/06/06/how-to-draw-a-cube-using-php/)

[create simple animated gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191367/php-create-simple-animated-gif-from-two-jpeg-images)

[create animated gif with php](http://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/weblog/php/howto-generate-animated-gif-with-php)

Comment: Wow... That looks... Promising?

Answer (score 1):

I have not experimented with it at all, but there is an OpenGL extension on github https://github.com/yoya/phpopengl. It appears to be a fork of a sourceforge project which has ceased development.

To my knowledge, this would be the only way to create true 3D graphics or animations using PHP.

Comment: If you think of it, since PHP can run extensions written in C, it doesn't sound SO crazy! But I can still say that "there is an OpenGL extension on PHP" and nobody will believe me :P