# PHP Image Convert

Tags: php, image

In my web app users are allowed to upload images as their photos. How can I convert different image extensions to **JPG**? Input files are **JPG, PNG** or **GIF**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert jpg image to gif, png & bmp format using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755781/convert-jpg-image-to-gif-png-bmp-format-using-php)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer [Image Magick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) over GD.  It's a lot better if you're dealing with large images too; you can run into memory allocation issues with GD.

Answer (score 3):

With php, you can convert any image to an other using imagepng, imagejpeg, imagegif :

```
imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($input)), 'output.png');
```

In this example, it will save the uploaded image in png with the path 'output.png'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**PHP GD**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who would want to get the binary out of a temporary file, here is my solution:

```php
<?php
   $temp = tmpfile();
   imagepng(imagecreatefromstring($imgBinary), $temp);
   $pathFile = stream_get_meta_data($temp)['uri']; // eg: /tmp/phpFx0513a
   $pngBin = file_get_contents($pathFile)
?>
```