# Use PHP to convert JPEGs to transparent PNG

Tags: php, png, image-manipulation, gd, jpeg

I have a lot of JPEG images that I want to convert to PNG images using PHP.
The JPEGs are going to be uploaded by clients so I can't trust them to make sure they are in the right format.

I also want to make their white backgrounds transparent.

Does PHP have any functions I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a few days of trying different solutions and doing some more research,
this is what I found worked for me.

```
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( 'image.jpg' );
 imagealphablending($image, true);
 $transparentcolour = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,255,255);
 imagecolortransparent($image, $transparentcolour)
```

The `imagealphablending($image, true);` is important.

Using `imagesavealpha($f, true);` as mentioned in a previous answer definitely doesn't work and seems to actually prevent you from making the background transparent...

To output the transparent image with the correct headers.

```
<?php
     header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
     imagepng( $image, null, 1 );
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$f = imagecreatefromjpeg('path.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($f, 255,255,255);
imagecolortransparent($f, $white);
```

More details [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

Comment: Assuming this will work, mind that JPG is a lossy format. That means that colors may be off a little, especially around the edges and in places where the color changes from white to another color. Looking for just plain white will probably not find all the pixels you want to be transparent.

Comment: Just to complete this answer: use `imagesavealpha($f, true);` to ensure the alpha channel is saved and `imagepng($f, '/path/to/save/file.png');` to save as PNG.

Comment: @awm added to my answer if you do not care

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( "image.jpg" );
 imagealphablending($image, true);
 imagepng($image, "image.png");
```

Answer (score -3):

I found this solution at [Convert jpg image to gif, png & bmp format using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755781/convert-jpg-image-to-gif-png-bmp-format-using-php)

```
$imageObject = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
imagegif($imageObject, $imageFile . '.gif');
imagepng($imageObject, $imageFile . '.png');
imagewbmp($imageObject, $imageFile . '.bmp');
```

Comment: You haven't answered the transparency question.