# How convert from other format to png format when using file_get_contents method?

Tags: php, format-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert jpg image to gif, png & bmp format using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755781/convert-jpg-image-to-gif-png-bmp-format-using-php)

I am using the file_get_contents method to obtain a JPEG image file from a url.  How do I convert it to a PNG file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean convert.

You can use the GD Library, more specifically the imagepng() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFileURL);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

This page will output the image in .png format.

If you are massing this with loops, you can save the files with

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFileURL);
imagepng($im, 'filename.png');
```