# Image Type of Profile Picture Downloaded from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

In my android app, I have downloaded profile pictures of Facebook users using the Graph API: `"http://graph.facebook.com/" + params[0]+ "/picture?width=150"`

I would like to save it to the local storage private to the app but I don't know what image type Facebook uses to send to Graph API users. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this question asked here it is gif for those who have not uploaded picture and jpg for those who have. [How to fetch facebook profile picture in png format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341770/how-to-fetch-facebook-profile-picture-in-png-format) and why is it hard to load it to a bitmap data type and decode it to any file type you want?

Comment: The app is going to download a lot of images and there won't be time and processing resources on certain people's devices. Your answer solves our problem though. Thanks.