# Converting Image Files to JPEG

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a website where I allow users to upload photos of any type.

I.e gif, jpeg, png

Now, how can I convert the files on upload to JPEG, if they aren't already?

Thanks

Here is my PHP:

```
if ($_FILES['media']['size'] != 0) {
    $target= UPLOADPATH . $media;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['media']['tmp_name'], $target);
    $query= "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, story, media, date, view, type) VALUES    
            ('$user_id', '$story', '$media', now(), '$view', '1')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query)
        or die('error with query 2');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use PHP to convert PNG to JPG with compression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression)

Comment: The answer was already given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755781/convert-jpg-image-to-gif-png-bmp-format-using-php

Comment: Why do you want to convert them to jpg?  PNG and GIF are both perfectly valid formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you start off by reading the content of the uploaded files into `imagecreatefromstring()` with something like `file_get_content($filePath)`. From there you use one `imagejpeg` to write to another file with extension `.jpg`

Here is a sample:

```
$handle = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_content($filePath));
imagejpeg($handle,'newfile.jpg',100);
```

Reference

1. [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)
2. [imagecreatefromstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)
3. [file_get_content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 1):

Simply renaming their extensions will not do the trick, you'll need to use an image processor to alter the file.

Check out [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try functions like imagecreatefrom*()

[imagecreatefrompng(youimage);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)

[imagecreatefromgif(youimage);](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)

before use this functions you need to know the file format.

Then use [imagejpeg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) function